# Installing Burpsuite certification into root CA does not work on Android 10

Tags: ssl-certificate, adb, android-10.0, burp

Hi I am using a **rooted** Samsung A51 with Android 10 and I am working with burpsuite.

I tried to install the certificate of burpsuite into the `/system/etc/security/cacerts/<hash>.0`, but it is not working when I proxy to my laptop, many of TLS error came out.

I had tried the certificated that worked on an HTC Android 9, copy it from HTC-Android-9/cacerts to Android-10/cacerts, but it still not working on Android 10.

I tried to follow the guideline [Configuring Burp Suite With Android Nougat](https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-burp-suite-with-android-nougat/#install-burp-ca-as-a-system-level-trusted-ca) or using [Magisk AlwaysTrustUserCerts](https://pswalia2u.medium.com/install-burpsuites-or-any-ca-certificate-to-system-store-in-android-10-and-11-38e508a5541a).

Does anyone have ideas or installed the user client into root CA store before?

Comment: Does TLS interception works with any app on that phone? Note that latest Chrome versions seem not fail with an error about "Certificate Transparency". So it is important to check which apps work and which not and what error they display. Please check this and update your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used different app such as Chrome, Firefox, to make a connection to https://yahoo.com, both apps showed the TLS connection failed, and Chrome showed the warning message as Err_Cert_Authority_Invalid

Comment: I tested it with another android 10 (One plus), i checked that the System Certificate page displayed the PortSwigger Certificate for OnePlus and Samsung A51, and the certificate was turned on also.

Comment: I wonder if it would work when we just put the <hash>.0 into the ..../cacerts/ folders and make it to 644 and root:root, in android 10. Do we need to do another things to make our cert work with android 10?

Comment: If the certificate is listed in system certificates then it should be used. Firefox AFAIR does not use Android system certificate store so it is a bad app for cert tests. May be the root CA certificate generated by Burpsuite is invalid because of wrong options? I usually use mitmproxy or Fiddler Classic (plus CertMaker for iOS and Android plugin).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried mitmproxy before, but since it is not UI friendly for work, I shifted to use burp, may I know have you tried to use the Certificate of mitmproxy in the burpsuite?

Comment: Well, I also tired with a certificate that worked on Android 9, import it into Android 10, but it is failed to work on Android 10, that's why I confused if there is another options need to be set up in Android 10.

Comment: Sorry I don't use burp as it is commercial. If you don't like mitmproxy's text UI try `mitmweb`. The restrictions to CA and leaf certificates were increased over the time in Android. That is not configurable, so the used proxy that generates the certificates have to generate certificates that apply to those rules (e.g. maximum leaf certificate validity).

Comment: Thank you for your help, let me try on it, hope it works.